# how do i display query result in view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC RC2.

I have Two tables
1)Product (PID, PName, CIDfk);
2)Category(CID, CName);

So i query like these

```
var Product = from p in dc.Product
                       from C in dc.Category
                       where p.CIDfk == c.CID
                       select new { ProductName = p.PName, ProductCategory = c.CName };
return view();
```

where dc is database context of LINQ-to-SQL class (.dbml);

How do i display in view? where i pass Product? (in viewdata or in 'return view()')

Please help me out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can both use:

```
- ViewData["MyName"] = product.SingleOrDefault();
```

This way from the view you'd do:

```
 <% Product p = (Product)ViewData(p) %>
```

or populate the model:

```
ViewData.Model = product.SingleOrDefault();
```

This way from the view you'd do:

```
<%Product p = ViewData.Model%> //in case of a Strongly typed view
<%Product p = (Product)ViewData.Model%> //otherwise
```

After populating either ViewData or the Model you can call:

```
return View();
```

Another approach is calling the View overload that accepts the model as parameter, as tvanfosson said.

Comment: as you suggest
<%Product p = ViewData.Model%> //in case of a Strongly typed view
<%Product p = (Product)ViewData.Model%> //otherwise

in second second way, how can i have a type Product ? I mean is there any namespace required to import?

Comment: if the entities are declared in a different namespace than the view, you have to import it in the view: 
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace" %>. 
If it's in the same namespace you don't have to import anything

Answer (score 2):

You want to have a strongly typed view and pass the product as the view model

```
 var product = from p in dc.Product
                   from C in dc.Category
                   where p.CIDfk == c.CID
                   select p;

 return View( product );
```

where your view is of type `ViewPage<Product>`.

Comment: That won't compile. You're passing a model of type IQueryable<Anonymous type>, but the view page model parameter is a different type. You could change the query to select p;

Comment: how do i cast a type of view page?

Comment: @Craig -- you're right.  I didn't look closely enough.  I'll update my answer to select the product.

Comment: @Vikas -- If you have a codebehind file -- they aren't created by default since RC1 -- you can just change the page class to inherit from ViewPage<Product>.  If not, change the Inherits specification in the ASPX file to inherit from ViewPage<Product>.